# Alfresco : Is it possible to add custom metadata/properties using REST APIS for a content or file.

Tags: api, rest, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need a system where end user can upload a content/file and also they can add custom
    metadata for it.
    To achieve it I gone through alfresco REST APIs. 
    I can upload a content/file on alfresco. But I can't able to add custom metadata.

Is it possible to add custom metadata/properties using REST APIs?

Comment: did you double-post your question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408807/alfresco-restful-services-to-create-custom-metadata

Comment: Yes posted it repeated times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a module with model and custom aspects or types that will hold the custom metadata.

Then you will upload the file and set properties using alfresco rest webscripts.

For adding aspects you can use this webscript
...alfresco/s/script/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/action/aspects.post

If you do not want two http request(upload and aspects) you can create custom script that will handle upload and adding custom properties( aspects, values and so on).

For creating modules,custom aspects and types with alfresco maven sdk you can use this tutorial:
http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/05/10/maven-alfresco-sdk/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I said, is an end user can add custom metadata/properties? You know well, an end user never able to use maven-alfresco-sdk.

Comment: Will end user be able to call rest by himself and make http request or you will provide him with the user friendly UI for that?

Comment: Please look on the new question to understand my requirement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408807/alfresco-restful-services-to-create-custom-metadata

Comment: For alfresco you must specify model first and then save data into the model.